# Share screen size is too big

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to share an image. I created a share intent. For some reason the share screen appears too big. It appears big on both Galaxy s4 and Nexus 5, but appears good on Genymotion. How can I fix it?

The code:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///" + 
    image.getAbsolutePath()));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, MainMenu.this
    .getResources().getString(R.string.shareImage)));
```

The screen:
[image: The screen]

Comment: What are you testing this on? I've seen some image discrepancies in notification bar icons when using emulators, but never an activity like this. Check your emulator DPI, maybe, or use a default one...

Comment: In my emulator its fine, in my Galaxy s4 or Nexus 5 its too big (the photo is a screenshot from a real Galaxy s4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an unknown reason, what made the screen look big is -

`Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, MainMenu.this.getResources().getString(R.string.shareImage))`.

Just doing `startActivity(sharingIntent);` fixed my problem.